# Compare two columns in pandas to update date column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-comparison

I need to compare a certain range of value of a column with a specific string in another column to update the date column with 1,7, 30 days

```
Col A    ColB           colc
5          Internal     1-1-2022
7          external     1-1-2022
4          external     1-1-2022
3          external     1-1-2022
```

so if `df[ColA]<8` and `df[ColB]=External` add 7 days to df[colc]. if if `df[ColA]>=8` and `df[ColB]=External` add 30 days to df[colc] and if `df[ColB]=Internal` add 120 days to df[Colc]

Comment: is the date M-D-YYYY or D-M-YYYY? Can you have values other than internal/external? if Col A is 8 do you want 7 or 30?

Comment: yes that is the format D-M-YYYY. if Col A is 8 then 7 days is what i am looking for

Comment: the change your just made `df[ColA]<8` means if ColA is 8 -> 30 days, not 7 ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry, i just validated the condition thats why

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to handle all your conditions:

I simplified them to:

- if ColB is "Internal" -> add 120 days
- else, if ColA is ≤ 8 -> add 7 days
- else -> add 30 days

```
factor = np.select([df['ColB'].eq('Internal'), df['Col A'].le(8)], [120, 7], 30)
df['new'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['colc'], dayfirst=True)
               .add(pd.DateOffset(days=1)*a)
               .dt.strftime('%-d-%-m-%-Y')
             )
```

output:

```
   Col A      ColB      colc       new
0      5  Internal  1-1-2022  3-1-2022
1      7  external  1-1-2022  6-1-2022
2      4  external  1-1-2022  1-1-2022
3      3  external  1-1-2022  3-1-2022
```

Comment: why the new dates are not reflecting as 120,7 and 30? also if I want to add 
if ColB is "Internal" -> add 120 days
elif ColA is >= 6 and <= 8 -> add 7 days
elif ColA is >=8 -> add 1 days
else -> add 30 days

can you modify your code for this

Comment: Please provide the explicit expected output. With the provided example it added 120/7/7/7

Comment: Getting this error - TypeError: cannot perform __rmul__ with this index type: DatetimeArray

Comment: The Df[new] should reflect 
1-5-2022
8-1-2022
1-2-2022
1-2-2022

based on the condition - 120/7/30/30

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example as DataFrame constructor

Answer (score 0):

Using the same `np.select` as @mozway, I would suggest using `pd.Timedelta`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Col A': [5, 7, 4, 3], 
        'ColB': ['Internal', 'external', 'external', 'external'], 
        'colc': pd.to_datetime("1/1/2022", format="%m/%d/%Y")
    }
)

df['colc'] = [
    (a + pd.Timedelta(b, 'd')) for (a, b) in
    zip(df.colc, np.select([df['ColB'].eq('Internal'), df['Col A'].le(8)], [120, 7], 30))
]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Col A      ColB       colc
0      5  Internal 2022-05-01
1      7  external 2022-01-08
2      4  external 2022-01-08
3      3  external 2022-01-08
```

Comment: What is 'd'? in (a + pd.Timedelta(b, 'd'))

Comment: It stands for 'day' so it will add a number of days to the original date.

Comment: can we have one more condition added to the same code
ColB is "Internal" -> add 120 days 
elif ColA is >= 6 and <= 8 -> add 7 days 
elif ColA is >=8 -> add 1 days 
else -> add 30 days

Comment: Yes, you can customise the `np.select` to match your use case.

Comment: I am using
df['Col C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col C'])
df['Col C'] = df['Col C'].dt.date
df['Col C'] = [
    (a + pd.Timedelta(b, 'd')) for (a, b) in
    zip(df['Col C'], np.select([df['ColB'].eq('Internal'), df['Col A'].ge(8), (df['Col A'].ge(6) and df['Col A'].ge(8)), df['Col A'].le(6)], [120, 1, 7], 30))
]

print(df)

and i get  error - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().